# How to display the titles of a grouped histogram in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

Here is an example dataframe:

```
print(df.head(5))


     Days     State
0    1.2     IN
1    3.4     IN
2   18.8     CA
3   16.5     CA
4    0.2     IL
```

I have a dataframe that I am grouping to display histograms as such:

```
  df.groupby('State').hist(bins=10, label='Dept')
  plt.show()
```

Lets say there are only 3 States: IN, IL, and CA.

This displays the 3 histograms, but the titles are not displaying the states, but rather just say 'Country' for each one.  How can I set this up to have the states listed as the titles?

this kinda of accomplishes what I am after:

```
df.hist(by=df['State'], bins=30)
plt.show()
```

But I don't like how it puts the histograms on a automatic grid.  Is there anyway to just show them separately, on top of each other like it does in the top code?

To rephrase my question, when there are 9 states in the data, the df.hist(by=df['State'], bins=30) will have 9 histograms in a 3x3 grid, 3 histograms wide, 3 tall.

This is an issue because it makes them each too small and labels overlap. I'm not sure how to adjust the layout to make the histograms larger and in a single column with a scroll bar in jupyter for example.

Comment: So, you want a legend?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] and may be, a more clear explanation of expected answer?

Comment: I have added more detail to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`layout` and `figsize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#using-layout-and-targeting-multiple-axes):

```
df.hist(by=df['State'], bins=30, layout=(3,1), figsize=(5,15))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for but for some reason could articulate how to search for it.

Comment: Actually, I didn't search for it, I was exposed to the layout parameter for pandas plot before on Stack Overflow.  The only other way you would know is to read  the pandas documentation.

Comment: @user76595 Trying to answer SO questions helps you learn the little things abount pandas and matplotlib.